# I can't connect to an instance of SSMS from other servers SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I can log in to the server and connect to the instance of SSMS in the server but I can't connect to the same instance from other servers using ssms. how can I fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting? What user are you using to connect to the SQL Server instance from SSMS on the host server and what user are you using to connect from SSMS on the other servers? How is security set up for this (these) user (users)?

Answer (score 2):

Start by making sure that your Firewall isn't blocking incoming connections to port 1433 (if this is a default instance installation). Check both the Windows Firewall and also the settings on your network firewall ( if you have one configured ).

Also make sure that remote connections are enabled to the SQL server (in SSMS, right click the instance -> Properties -> Connections -> Allow Remote Connections to this server)